# “other’s lives” vs. “others’ lives”

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, punctuation, apostrophe

I'm not sure which of the following is correct:

> having an impact on other’s lives
>
> having an impact on others’ lives

I just can’t figure out how the apostrophe should be used.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since you are talking about multiple others ("...the lives of others"), then the apostrophe comes after the *s*.

> having an impact on others' lives

Answer (score 1):

If something is singular, for example, Bob.  Then he is a person and we write

> Bob's book.

Let us consider there are two Bobs and both of them share a single book.

> The two Bobs' book

so *others* is plural. Consequently, the correct answer is

> having an impact on others’ lives.

Answer (score 0):

Let's be simple.
I have many students, and one of them is John.
I am checking exam copies.

> 1. I am checking John's paper.
> 2. I have checked all of my students' paper.
> 3. One son went to live in Australia and the other one was killed in a car crash.
> 4. One son went to live in Australia and the others were killed in a car crash.

others –> others' lives.

Comment: "I have checked all of my students' paper" doesn't make sense (it would only work if "paper" were being used as a mass noun). It would be better to write "I have checked all of my students' paper**s**".